# ranking 2 matrices separately after the sequence of a third matrix

Tags: r

I have two matrices A and B (both 4x4), which represents rankings. Group1 are the order 1-4 and Group 2 are the order 5-8.

```
A:                     B: 
(1 2 3 4)..............(5 6 7 8) 
(1 2 3 4)..............(5 6 7 8) 
(1 2 3 4)..............(5 6 7 8) 
(1 2 3 4)..............(5 6 7 8)
```

Then I have an other matrix C (4x8 matrix), which has the order 1-8 (but) in an other constellation:

```
C:
(8 3 1 4 2 7 5 6) 
(5 1 7 3 6 2 8 4) 
(7 3 2 1 8 4 6 5) 
(4 2 1 6 7 8 5 3)
```

Now, I want to reorder matrix A and matrix B after the scheme/sequence of C. The solution should look like this:

```
A_new:                B_new:
(3 1 4 2)             (8 7 5 6) 
(1 3 2 4)             (5 7 6 8) 
(3 2 1 4)             (7 8 6 5) 
(4 2 1 3)             (6 7 8 5)
```

I hope someone has a hint for me, because with the normal "sort" and "order" functions I had no success.

Comment: I do not know how it works in R, but if it was in any other language like `ruby`, I would have just subtracted the matrix row by row for e.g. A['first_row'] = C['first_row'] - B['first_row'], where C['first_row'] contains [8,3,1,4,2,7,5,6] (an array), B['first_row'] contains [5,6,7,8], which would result into A['first_row'] = [3,1,4,2]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using in C is the order of 1 to 4 and the order of 5 to 8 in each row.

#### Code to check:

```
set.seed(123)
A<-matrix(1:4,nrow = 4,ncol =4,byrow = T)
B<-matrix(5:8,nrow = 4,ncol =4,byrow = T)
C<-matrix(sample(x = 1:8,size = 8),nrow = 4,ncol =8,byrow = T)
```

#### I stored results in a different matrix

```
A1<-matrix(nrow = 4,ncol = 4)
B1<-matrix(nrow = 4,ncol = 4)
```

#### The results

```
for(i in 1:nrow(C)){
  vect<-C[i,]
  A1[i,]<-A[i,vect[vect<=ncol(A)]]
  B1[i,]<-B[i,(vect[vect>ncol(A)])-ncol(A)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it do not works.I got the error: unexpected symbol "A[i,]<-A[i,C[i,C[i,C[i,]<=ncol(A)]]
           B"  It could be that brackets are missing, but when I add them I got the error message "Indexing beyond ranges". Do you have an idea?

Comment: Okay, now I have the error message: unexpected symbol: ')' in: 
"  A[i,]<-A[i,C[i,C[i,C[i,]<=ncol(A)]]]
  B[i,]<-B[i,(C[i,C[i,C[i,]>ncol(A)])" But when I delete it or replace it, I got the other error message "Indexing beyond ranges"

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed everything and added the code used to check.

Answer (score 0):

`A<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),4,4,byrow=T)
B<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),4,4,byrow=T)`

`C<-matrix(c(8,3,1,4,2,7,5,6,5,1,7,3,6,2,8,4,7,3,2,1,8,4,6,5,4,2,1,6,7,8,5,3),4,8,byrow=T)`

`for(i in 1:nrow(C)){

  A[i,]<-A[i,C[i,C[i,C[i,]<=ncol(A)]]]
  B[i,]<-B[i,(C[i,C[i,C[i,]>ncol(A)])-ncol(A)]]
}`

This is the code till now and I got the two error messages:
 unexpected symbol: ')' in: " A[i,]<-A[i,C[i,C[i,C[i,]<=ncol(A)]]] B[i,]<-B[i,(C[i,C[i,C[i,]>ncol(A)])"

and without brackets: "Indexing beyond ranges"

Thanks